# Is there a way to connect Python scripts to data on databricks without the cluster being active?

Tags: python, azure, databricks

My data is currently held in Azure, partitioned in parquet files in the DBFS which I can access through the Databricks CLI. While accessing the parquet files from my laptop is straightforward, I'd like to be able to do it programmatically from Python scripts.

Essentially, I'd like to access the data from Python scripts without the requirements of my cluster being active. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. There is [databricks-connect](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html) that you can use to connect from PyCharm to Databricks environment. Here are the rough steps involved (tested on Mac).

###### Requirements

```
Only the following Databricks Runtime versions are supported:

Databricks Runtime 8.1 ML, Databricks Runtime 8.1
Databricks Runtime 7.3 LTS ML, Databricks Runtime 7.3 LTS
Databricks Runtime 6.4 ML, Databricks Runtime 6.4
Databricks Runtime 5.5 LTS ML, Databricks Runtime 5.5 LTS
```

Install [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/macos.html) and [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) that you will later to switch env.

###### Create Conda virtualenv

```
conda create --name dbconnect python=3.8
```

###### Install and Configure JRE

```
brew install openjdk@8
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk@8/bin:$PATH"
```

###### Remove Pyspark

```
pip uninstall pyspark
```

###### Install DB Connect client

```
pip install -U "databricks-connect==8.1.*"
```

###### Configure connection properties

```
databricks-connect configure
```

[image]

###### Test connectivity to Databricks

```
databricks-connect test
```

**Note:** If the cluster you configured is not running, the test starts the cluster which will remain running until its configured autotermination time.

###### Set up PyCharm

**Note:** When you create a PyCharm project, select Existing Interpreter. From the drop-down menu, select the Conda environment you created

[image]

###### Run python code

```
python sample.py
```

Let me know if you get stuck with any step.

Comment: databricks-connect requires running cluster - that's what user explicitly asked for :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, this method requires the cluster to be active which is the obstacle I am trying to overcome.